# Episerver Some images, that really are used, have "no related pages" in filesummary

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

In Episerver FileManagement some images have "no related pages" in filesummary, but there are pages, that use these pictures. Update, site restart, reindexing didn't help.
Images are displayed by some control that gets image path from PropertyImageUrl (or some other, I tried PropertyString too) type property. Control is rendering like

```
var imageControl = new Image();
imageControl.ImageUrl = MediaFile; //string MediaFile - comes from property
imageControl.AlternateText = AltText;
if (ImageHeight != 0) imageControl.Height = ImageHeight;
if (ImageWidth != 0) imageControl.Width = ImageWidth;
Controls.Add(imageControl);
```

But some images are just statically written  tags with static src value like

```
<img src="/Global/image.jpg"/>
```

No one of these approaches (use control or static  tag) did not work on one new-added to episerver file system image - it still had "no related pages".
But some other images in file manager has normally displaying related pages, rendering of these images on their related pages happens in the same way, as I described above. 
VPP providers are default, filesummary.config is default also.
It just seems that some random images, that really are used, have no related pages in filesummary. This seems not to depend on the way images are displayed on pages.
Maybe you have some information regarding the way Episerver creates "related pages" list in filesummary? What else can I try? Maybe it takes episerver a time to renew this information? Where it is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPiServer indexes references with some delay, so you won't see result immediately, but you will definitely see result in say a minute after publishing.

Image and page links will be indexed **only if** they are contained in **page data properties** with **property types** which implements `IReferenceMap`. In some cases such properties should be marked as `IsSearchable`.

So, you can expect indexing of images from the following Property Types:

- `PropertyUrl`, `PropertyFileUrl`, `PropertyDocumentUrl`, `PropertyImageUrl`
- `PropertyXhtmlString`
- `ProperyLinkItemCollection`
- Bonus property - `PropertyPageReference` as EPiServer treats it separately from all others. Noting to deal with images, but good to know

Comment: I think I just haven't wait enough after setting picture on page. Now I tried to add picture in PropertyImageUrl and wait, and related page appeared in filesummary. Thanks!
Now I will try to inherit specific property (that now inherits PropertyPropertyDataCollection) also from IReferenceMap, any tips on doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Images in templates aren't "indexed", so they wouldn't have a related page.

If you would select one of those images in a PropertyImageUrl or XHTML property (i.e, through the TinyMCE editor), would it then have a related page?